# specifying type of content in rest.Resource (rest.go lib & Golang)

Tags: url, go

I write a json data structure, 
and store it in the url as a resource

```
type FileString struct {
    Data string
 }
rest.Resource("json_data", &FileString{Data : some_string})
```

but when I load it in the java-script, as a uri

```
 loader.load( { model: '/json_data/', callback: function ( geometry ) {
  ...
  }
```

I get in the js console

> 'Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.'

Where do I set the content type when doing `rest.Resource(...)` ???
Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. rest.go doesn't expose that functionality.
You could file an issue with the developer.

Answer (score 1):

[Goweb's API stuff](http://code.google.com/p/goweb/wiki/BuildingAPIs) provides much more control over the underlying HTTP allowing you to specify content type in the usual way.